# How do I make different variables in for loops In Python

Tags: python

I am making a program that has a for loop and every time the loop is ran I want it to make a new variable like

```
for item in range(0, size)
     (Make new variable bit1, bit2, bit3, bit4, etc with value of 0)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The easiest is with `globals()["bit" + str(i+1)] = 0`. But most likely it is a bad idea, and you should use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `List` of variables and append to it like this:

```
bits = []
for item in range(0, size)
    bits.append(0)

# now you have bits[0], bits[1], bits[2], etc, all set to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by appending to the `vars()` dictionary in the program.

```
for index, item in enumerate(range(size)):
     vars()[f'bit{index+1}'] = 0
```

Try calling the names now:

```
>>> bit1
0
```

And while this works, I'd recommend using a `list` or a `dict` instead.